# Mapping Welcome file depending on the user role in Spring

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

My Web app has two roles, User and Admin and each has different jsp pages. Now how can i map different Welcome files for these two different users ? 
Server/webapp/user.jsp for USer
server/webpp/admin.jsp for Admin

Lets say, If added welcome file as user.jsp/user home page. How can i add a condition in user.jsp for admin users ? I feel Cookies or Filters can help.

Comment: If it's the first page (index page), how will you determine user's role? If it's dashboard/home page, @Optio 's solution works

Answer (score 1):

Here are two variants.

**Variant 1.** You can use **annotations** and make different files for each role.
For example, your Admin has role `"ROLE_ADMIN"`.

Just add this:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')")
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String getAdmin() {
return "admin";
}
```

And the same for users:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@RequestMapping("/login")
public String getUser() {
return "user";
}
```

**Variant 2.** If you want do something special inside the .jsp file depending on the role, use this:

```
<sec:authorize access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')">
This content will only be visible to users who have
the "ROLE_ADMIN" authority in their list of <tt>GrantedAuthority</tt>s.
</sec:authorize>
```

To make this tag work - add this at the begining of the.jsp file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
```

More about `authorize` tag [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You could handle it in the controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/loginUser")
    public String controllerLogin(){
        String userType = //code to get user type

        //code to get view depending on the userType (like a switch)

        return "view";
    }
```

If you return a string without @RequestBody it's treated as view name.
This is from Spring 3.X which I guess it's what you are using.

Comment: Thanks. Lets say i added welcome file as user.jsp/user home page. How can i add a condition in user.jsp for admin users ?

Comment: well, you could use JSTL,

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm)